# Start a process after a certain time interval in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a c# wpf application where in the main() method, I check for a certain condition and if it is true, I run a different process, however, I need to start the process after a certain timeout. So, for eg:

```
override OnStartUp()

    {
           if(condition == true)
           {
                ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("filePath");
                p.Start(); // This should wait for like say 5 seconds and then start.
                  return;   // This will exit the current program.
            }
    }
```

I could use Thread.Sleep() but that will cause the current program to sleep as well.
So, in other words, I want the current program to terminate immediately and then new process to start after 5 seconds.

Thanks!

Is this possible?

Comment: Use a `Timer` to perform some action after X time period

Comment: @Servy: That can't cause an action after the current process has already terminated.

Comment: Yes..the current process must be terminated and ONLY after the new process needs to wait for 5 secs to start...thanks

Comment: For reference...the fact that you need to wait at all smells of a race condition.  You might want to look at getting rid of the bug that causes it rather than trying to duct-tape over it.  In almost all cases, for example, you don't want to wait *for exactly 5 seconds*, you want to wait *til XYZ is done*.  Wait for that instead.

Comment: For the sake of alternative solutions could you provide why you need this app to close before your 5 second wait occurs. Also is the app it is starting also open to modification (as in you have the source and can change it to accept a wait environment variable or something of the like)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few options:

1. Modify the process being launched and put the delay there.  You can even wait for "the parent has ended" instead of a fixed time.
2. Windows built-in Scheduled Tasks
3. A batch file that uses the sleep command and then runs the program

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't think a scheduled task would be up to this.  5 seconds is too small a wait; IIRC the task scheduler has a granularity of a minute.

Comment: @cHao: I don't know the actual precision, but the API accepts a granularity of seconds: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383967(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: hey Ben....what do you mean by "parent has ended" is there an event that I can hook into?

Comment: A process object becomes signaled when the process terminates, and it's relatively easy to get a handle to your parent process.

Answer (score 4):

What if the first process creates a third program.  The first program exits immediately, whilst the third one will simply sleep for 5 seconds and then will start your second program.

Comment: That is a smart way to do it...but writing 3 separate programs is not really an option. Thank you tho.

Comment: I got the impression that there must definitely be a certain interval between the time the first program exits and the time the second program starts.  If the second program can start immediately and wait for as long as you needed then option 1 in Ben Voigt's answer is the way to go.  This is a common scenario in programs with the auto-updating feature.  The updater has to be started by the program itself but the updater cannot start overwriting the main program until it exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Task Scheduler api and setup one time task that will start app after next 5 seconds.Nice managed wrraper: taskscheduler.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Thread. In this thread you can use Thread.Sleep without blocking your program.

```
public class MyThread
{
   public static void DoIt()
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      // DO what you need here
   }
}
override OnStartUp()
{
    if(condition == true)
    {
       ThreadStart myThread = new MyThread(wt.DoIt);
       Thread myThread = new Thread(myThread);
       myThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It does block the process from exiting, which is a requirement listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can recomend the very powerful

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

For all your scheduling needs.

Comment: That blocks (in the `WaitOne` call).  The question requires that the current program ends before the action takes place.